# Converter char para hora

Tags: r

Preciso converter um campo de um arquivo de char para algo que seja calculável a média.

Trata-se de um campo que se refere a horas originalmente.

```
system.time(cpc_call<-fread("ACIONAMENTO_CALL.csv",header = T , sep= ";")) # Importa tabela
```

Quando vou ver o arquivo importado o mesmo aparece como chr.

Então na tentativa de converter , fiz o codigo abaixo:

```
cpc_call$Tempo_Falado = as.numeric(cpc_call$Tempo_Falado) # Transforma tempo falado em tempo

cpc_call %>%
group_by(Outcome) %>%
summarise(median(cpc_call$Tempo_Falado))
```

Porém o resultado da coluna referente a media retorna apenas "NA"

Edit : Segue a saida com : dput(head(cpc_call$Tempo_Falado, 20))

```
> dput(head(cpc_call$Tempo_Falado, 20))
c("00:01:20", "00:01:46", "00:01:36", "00:05:26", "00:01:37", 
"00:05:11", "00:02:34", "00:01:32", "00:01:44", "00:02:51", "00:02:45", 
"00:01:45", "00:02:22", "00:02:04", "00:03:17", "00:01:59", "00:01:44", 
"00:01:31", "00:01:23", "00:01:43")
```

Comment: Como está `cpc_call$Tempo_Falado` antes do início do código? Dê alguns exemplos que facilita para o povo ajudar.

Comment: Ajudou , pois antes disso tenho apenas as lib e o setwd?

Comment: Ponha a saída de `dput(head(cpc_call$Tempo_Falado, 20))` na pergunta. Assim podemos ter uma cópia exata dos dados e ver qual o problema e a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o pacote `chron` você consegue transformar o seu vetor de *character* para o tipo *times* , que vai te permitir realizar operações como média, mediana.

```
cpc_call <- c("00:01:20", "00:01:46", "00:01:36", "00:05:26", "00:01:37", 
"00:05:11", "00:02:34", "00:01:32", "00:01:44", "00:02:51", "00:02:45", 
"00:01:45", "00:02:22", "00:02:04", "00:03:17", "00:01:59", "00:01:44", 
"00:01:31", "00:01:23", "00:01:43")
library(chron)
cpc_call <- chron(times = cpc_call)
```

Com esses valores, o valor da média foi

```
mean(cpc_call)
[1] 00:02:18
```

E fazendo a conferência (em segundos),

```
mean(60*minutes(cpc_call) + seconds(cpc_call))
[1] 138.5
```